# internet slow on my tablet

Tags: wi-fi, internet, prestigio-multipad

> I know this question has been asked over and over and I have searched
>   for an answer but no one seems to have an good result.

I have a new **Prestigio Multipad 10.1**. It's a nice tablet but I'm having trouble connecting it to my WiFi. I can connect but it's slow or never seems to receive any data.

I've tried a lot but I haven't a clue why other devices I have work. My android phone, my laptop, iPod etc.

I bought two of these and they both have the same problem.

There must be a setting which will correct this problem.

I have tried changing channels, I have tried a WiFi fixer but:

- **Google store just times out.**
- **Chrome never comes back with any results .**

I'm pulling my hair out. Please help.

Comment: You haven't specified what you have tried so we'll end up recommending things you've already tried. Start here I guess: http://www.guidingtech.com/13028/solutions-android-wi-fi-problems-common/

Comment: See what RossC said,... and, when you are too far away from your access point, the wifi module of your mobile phone might lose packages that are sent to the access point, as wifi modules of smaller devices usually have a weaker sender / less range than those of larger devices.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I have an explanation for you but it seems to be the nature of the beast. On my wifi network, my smartphone and my tablet get about 10mbps slower speed than my computer. I have no idea why but that's consistently the result so that must be normal.

Answer (score 0):

The manufacturer of your tablet may have put a chip for older standards of wifi, such as N or G. The computer will always be faster as it has larger antennas if on wifi, or is wired through the modem to the router to the computer using Ethernet. Wired connections are always going to be faster than wireless.